# OpenCv Shape Detection To Shape Transformation (Pythhon)

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

How can I take a image of a square that has been detected using shape detection algorithm on openCV and "Transform" it to a triangle the quickest way possible?

For EXAMPLE say one of the images from google is a square and i want to see the fastsest way to turn it to a triangle. How would I go about researching this? I have looked up shape transformation for openCV but it mostly covers zooming in on the image and changing views.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the **tour** (https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), "What Are Good Topics" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please show an example of what you want. Do you want to cut out a triangle from the middle or warp the rectangle into a triangle? Please be more specific.

Comment: I think what you might want is a perspective transformation where the top two corner of the square are warped to nearly the same point as the apex of the triangle. See cv2.warpPerspective() at https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#gaf73673a7e8e18ec6963e3774e6a94b87

Answer (score 0):

One way to distort a rectangle to a triangle is to use a perspective transformation in Python/OpenCV.

- Read the input
- Get the input control points as the 4 corners of the input image
- Define the output control points as to top 2 points close to the top center of the output (-+1 or whatever separation you want) and bottom 2 points the same as the input bottom two points
- Compute the perspective transformation matrix from the control points
- Warp the input to the output
- Save the result.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Read source image.
img_src = cv2.imread('lena.png')
hh, ww = img_src.shape[:2]

# Four corners of source image ordered clockwise from top left corner
# Coordinates are in x,y system with x horizontal to the right and y vertical downward
pts_src = np.float32([[0,0], [ww-1,0], [ww-1,hh-1], [0,hh-1]])

# Four corners of destination image.
pts_dst = np.float32([[ww/2-1, 0], [ww/2+1,0], [ww-1,hh-1], [0,hh-1]])

# Get perspecive matrix if only 4 points
m = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(pts_src,pts_dst)

# Warp source image to destination based on matrix
img_out = cv2.warpPerspective(img_src, m, (ww,hh), cv2.INTER_LINEAR, borderMode=cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, borderValue=(255, 255, 255))

# Save output
cv2.imwrite('lena_triangle.png', img_out)

# Display result
cv2.imshow("Warped Source Image", img_out)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Result (though likely not what you want).

[image]

If you separate the top two output points by a larger difference, then it will look more like the input.

For example, using ww/2-10 and ww/2+10 rather than ww/2-1 and ww/2+1 for the top two output points, I get:

[image]